# Bootstrap Extra padding inside div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm implementing a userscript (in Tampermonkey) for a website I frequently use, and I'm trying to add a div to the page. All's well if I add the div to the top of the page (to the root element):

[image]

But as soon as I add it inside a Bootstrap column, I get some annoying extra padding as seen below:

[image: weird padding]

I've tried fiddling with the styling through the Chrome Developer Tools and the only way I could get the padding to disappear was by deleting all the elements occurring before in the column and also setting the ":before" element in the parent row to "display:inline". I think I'm probably misunderstanding how Bootstrap works and there's probably an easy fix, but I've been experimenting for a while and searching online and I haven't found anyone with a similar issue. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the padding issue, and how I might fix it?

**Edit:** the Bootstrap version seems to be 3.3.2 (I can't update it as this is a userscript) and the HTML, once inserted, looks like the following (the "project-dropdown" element is the one I have inserted):

[image]

The CSS applied to the "project-dropdown" element looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your actual code? Also make sure you are using the correct version of Bootstrap

Comment: While fiddling with the style have you tried `padding: 0 0 0 0 !important` ?

Comment: Yes, that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Strange.. Have you checked the parents padding? Maybe try a negative margin as workaround, for example `margin: 0 -20px !important;`. Experiment to get to the correct amount of px.

Comment: Did you try removing the `padding` on the `col` itself?

Comment: Removing the padding on the col element seems to remove the padding on the sides of the box, but there's still extra padding on the bottom.

Comment: @jfdoming the padding is introduced by the `col-xx-xx` class, you have to change the style at **that** element. Removing padding at a column child’s level won’t work.

Comment: Yes, that's where I removed the padding; it had the effect I described above.

Comment: There’s a `row` parent class too...

Comment: Hmmm... @DavideVitali You seem to be correct, removing the padding on the parent with the row class fixes the issue. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @jfdoming because the “C” in CSS stands for **Cascading**: styles you apply to one element will have effect on its children too.

Comment: I understand that, I guess I'm wondering because I had tried applying the same style everywhere else and it had no effect. Oh well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `project-dropdown` element has a parent class `col-x-x` that introduced left and right padding. On top of that, said column is placed in a `row` class, introducing top and bottom padding.

Because of the nature of **CSS** itself, those properties will be “inherited” by children elemen too. To remove all padding, override the default value at the parent `col` and `row` classes.

Cheers!

Comment: Quick follow-up: after a bit more experimentation I discovered that this extra space only gets added if the padding on the parent is of the form 4n+3px (e.g. 3px, 7px...). This seems really weird, any idea why that might be?

Comment: Because the `row` class add a **negative** margin and -more generally - every padding or margin is the sum of the paddings and margin introduced by their parents. Things could get quite messy if not done carefully ;) @jfdoming

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything, I've disabled that CSS and this error still occurs, albeit with different numbers (e.g. 16px).

Comment: In fact, it seems that even if I add `* { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; }` the issue still persists.